# How to select or find new file in directory linux

Tags: linux, grep, find, backup, scp

I want to use scp to backup 1 directory from server. But my problem is backup directory have so many file (old & new file) . I just want to copy new file such as .

file 1 - last modify: 2022-10-11

file 2 - last modify: 2022-10-12

file 3 - last modify: 2022-10-13

file 4 - last modify: 2022-10-14

so, how can i use find command to select only file 4 ? because i think if i select new file i can use | and scp command to copy only new file.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With the zsh shell:

```
scp ./file*(.om[1]) host:target/dir/
```

Would `scp` the newest (in terms of last modification time) regular (`.` glob qualifier) file in the current working directory whose name starts with `file`.

With GNU utilities and any Bourne-like shell, you can do something similar with:

```
{
  {
    LC_ALL=C find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'file*' -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0'  |
      LC_ALL=C sort -z -k1,1rn |
      head -zn1 |
      cut -zf2-
  } 4<&- |
    xargs -0a /dev/fd/3 -I FILE scp FILE host:target/dir/ 3<&0 <&4 4<&- 
} 4<&0
```

(untested).

To select files last modified after 2022-10-14T00:00:00 local time, with BSD/GNU `find`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'file*' -type f -newermt 2022-10-14 \
  -exec sh -c 'exec scp "$@" host:target/dir/' sh {} +
```

Or  with `zsh`:

```
autoload after
scp ./file*(.e['after 2022-10-14']) host:target/dir/
```

(contrary to `find`'s `-newermt`, it would also transfer files modified at exactly 2022-10-14T00:00:00.000000000).

To also consider files in subdirectories, remove the  `-maxdepth 1` or replace `./file` with `./**/file` in `zsh`. Beware that `find` will also consider  files in hidden directories. Add the `D` glob qualifier in `zsh` if you want that behaviour there as well. Excluding hidden dirs in `find` is a matter of calling `-prune` on directories other than `.` (the start directory here) whose name starts with `.`: `LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o ...`

Comment: Why using this complex `find` command? Why not `"$(ls -t1 |head -1)"` (for modify time) or `"$(ls -ct1 |head -1)"` (for change time)?

Comment: @aviro, you can't use line-based utilities for file paths since newline is as valid a character as any in file paths. With recent versions of GNU `ls`, you could use `ls --zero -td ./file* | head -zn1`, but even that doesn't do the `-type f`. You'd need zsh's `./file*(.)` to restrict the glob expansion to *regular* file, but if you have zsh, you don't need `ls` to sort the files by mtime.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command has builtin option to search files by time:

For last **write** time (m like *modification*):
`find . -mtime n`

For last **read** time (a like *access*):
`find . -atime n`

- `+n` for **n** days or more
- `-n` for **n** days or less
- `n` for exactly **n** days

Full example:

```bash
find . -mtime +6 -type f
```

Will find all files in current directory and sub-directories that were modified 7 days ago or more.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599094/explaining-the-find-mtime-command).

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't answer your specific question about finding the last file, but for backup purposes, it's better to use `rsync` instead of `scp`.

From the man pages of `rsync(1)`:

> rsync is a program that behaves in much the same way that scp does,
> but  has many more options and uses the rsync remote-update protocol
> to greatly  **speed up file transfers when the destination file already
> exists.** Rsync is  widely **used for backups and mirroring** and as an
> improved copy command for  everyday use.
>
> Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a "quick check"
> algorithm (by default) that **looks for files that have changed in size
> or  in last-modified time.** Any changes in the other preserved
> attributes (as  requested by options) are made on the destination file
> directly when the  quick check indicates that the file's data does not
> need to be updated.

An example use to copy the current working directory to a destination host:

```
rsync -avz ./ host:target/dir
```

- `-a` - archive mode. It means it will copy the entire folder recursively, and preserve permissions, owner, group and modification time.
- `-v` - increase verbosity. This will show you which files have actually been copied.
- `-z` - compress file data during the transfer in order to reduce the size of data portions of the transfer.

Comment: Hi , can i ask more . How can we use ssh key with rsync together ?? because if we don't use ssh key , it will ask root password everytime.

Comment: i can use ssh file with command : rsync -avzhe "ssh -i /path/keyfile" /sourcebk/ root@ip_dest:/dest_dir